# How can I use the Win32::LongPath module in Perl to manipulate long path names?

Tags: windows, perl, path, long-path

My Perl scripts need to work with pathnames that are longer than 260 characters, and I can not turn on the feature in the registry to enable [Windows Long Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd) support.

I included a small Perl test, using the [`Win32::LongPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::LongPath) module to do this, and found that only a few functions from that module work. No luck with:

- [`chdirL`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::LongPath#chdirL-PATH)
- [`getcwdL`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::LongPath#getcwdL)

Environment:

- Windows 10 version 10.0.19041 build 19041
- Strawberry Perl 5.30.3

I can't really find evidence that `Win32::LongPath` will not work in that environment, except for CPAN saying that the module has only been tested on XP and Windows 8...

⚠ However all of the help for Perl/Windows Long Paths in Windows 10 seems to recommend this module?

Am I using it wrong? I have included the output of the last iteration of the loop in the MRE (Minimal Reproducible Example):

- The `chdirL` command never changes directories.
- The `getcwdL` command only has 249 characters (513 expected).

```perl
package main 1.0;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Carp;

use Readonly;
use File::Spec::Functions;
use Cwd;

use Win32::LongPath;

my $dir       = 'd123456789';
my $file      = 'test.txt';
my $long_path = 'C:\\Temp';
my $long_file;
my $long_root = catdir $long_path, $dir;
my $fh;

# Maximum path length on linux   : 4096
# Maximum path length on Windows :  260
Readonly::Scalar my $MAX_PATH => 512;

chdirL $long_path;

while ( length $long_path < $MAX_PATH ) {
  $long_path = catdir $long_path,  $dir;
  $long_file = catfile $long_path, $file;

  printf "%-5d: %s\n", length $long_path, "Making $long_path...";
  mkdirL $long_path;
  # === Does not change directories ==>
  chdirL $long_path;
  system 'CD';
  # === Truncates path name ==>
  my $curdir = getcwdL;
  printf "%-20s: %s (%d)\n", 'getcwpdL', $curdir, length $curdir;

  printf "%-5d: %s\n", length $long_file, "Making $long_file...";
  openL \$fh, '>', $long_file or die "unable to create file\n";
  print {$fh} "$long_path\n" or die "unable to print to file\n";
  close $fh                  or die "unable to close file\n";


  last if ( !( testL 'e', $long_path ) );
  last if ( !( testL 'e', $long_file ) );

}

unlinkL $long_file or warn "unable to delete file\n";

1;
```

Last loop iteration:

```
513  : Making C:\Temp\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789...
W:\home\_PERL\long_path
getcwpdL            : C:\Temp\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789 (249)
522  : Making C:\Temp\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\d123456789\test.txt...
```

Answer (score 2):

`chdirL` is failing with `The filename or extension is too long`. `chdirL`, like the others, converts the path to a long path (`\\?\...`), and calls the appropriate system call. This is `SetCurrentDirectoryW` for `chdirL` and `GetCurrentDirectoryW` for `getcwdL`.

Using paths of the form `\\?\...` extends the use length limit for some calls, but not for `SetCurrentDirectoryW` and `GetCurrentDirectoryW`. It also doesn't extend the limit for `CreateDirectoryW`, `CreateDirectoryExW` and `RemoveDirectoryW`. These five retain the classical length limit even when using "long paths", at least according to [Maximum Path Length Limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd), which provides a registry setting PLUS a manifest entry you can use to remove the limit on long paths for those calls.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem]
"LongPathsEnabled"=dword:00000001
```

```xml
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings xmlns:ws2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">
        <ws2:longPathAware>true</ws2:longPathAware>
    </windowsSettings>
</application>
```

I don't remember if DLLs have their own manifest or not. If they do, the settings could be changed for just the module, and nothing would break. If they don't and `perl`'s manifest needs to be changed, this would affect all uses of `GetCurrentDirectoryW` in the process, and that could cause problems. (`GetCurrentDirectoryW` could return an error because the buffer is too small, which could lead to a failure or crash depending on whether error checking is performed.)

Comment: But the `mkdirL` works (I assume this gets mapped onto `CreateDirectoryW`)? That would explain why `chdirL` (`SetCurrentDirectoryW`) and `getcwdL` (`GetCurrentDirectoryW`) don't work. But I thought that the whole point of the `W` functions in the Windows API was that they actually work for long paths (as opposed to the `A` functions). And that was supposed to work even if you don't change the registry (nor the manifest)... Unfortunately, my scripts need to run on other machines, where I have no guarantee that the registry and manifest are taken care of...

Comment: Re "*But the `mkdirL` works*", Weird. But I didn't understand why it would need backwards compatibility flag. /// Re "*I assume this gets mapped onto CreateDirectoryW*", [yes](https://metacpan.org/release/RBOISVERT/Win32-LongPath-2.1a/source/xs/LongPath.xs#L144) /// Re "*But I thought that the whole point of the W functions in the Windows API was that they actually work for long paths*", No, they have nothing to do with paths at all. The difference is the character encoding used for text: UTF-16le for "W", and the Active Code Page for "A" functions.

Comment: Re "*I have no guarantee that the registry and manifest are taken care of*", That may be true for the Registry. But if the manifest is per DLL,, cause you could submit a change to Win32::LongPath.

Comment: CreateDirectoryW has supported \\?\ long paths for a very long time, current directory was one of the things left out back then (along with CreateProcess and LoadLibrary?).

Comment: @Anders GetCurrentDirectoryW` supports `\\?\`. It just doesn't let you give a longer path by default.